# Raid 5 Degraded

Tags: hard-drive, raid, software-raid

I have a dell PowerEdge T110 with a raid 5 array that says it is degraded. This uses a perc s100 controller. I am using 4 74gb raptor drives for the array.  The computer tries to boot but it hangs on the windows loading screen and when I go to safe mode it hangs at storport.sys. When I go into the raid controller I see two raid arrays both say raid5 but the sizes are different. one is 95gb and the other is 52gb but both say degraded. Also on the physical disks it has two drives online, one that says spare, and one that says ready. I didn't set this raid up and haven't worked much with raid so I need all the help I can get. 
Is there any way to find out what disk has failed or if it is the controller? Is it bad to just unplug a disk and put another one in to test if it is the bad drive?

Comment: `Is it bad to just unplug a disk and put another one in to test if it is the bad drive?` - Yes it is. If you pull the good disk and leave the bad one in you're risking losing the array and the data on it. Do you have physical access to the server? If so, look at the drive LED's. The failed/suspect drive LED should be amber or red. You can get a replacement drive and swap it out with the suspect/failed drive. Can you post some pictures of the array configuration showing the 2 arrays?

Comment: there aren't any LED's for the hard drives that I can see. It is a tower and just has a blinking squiggle on the front. I did find a self test and am running that now. hopefully that will tell me the drive.

Comment: My bad. I've got two T110's in front of me I could have looked at. The blinking squiggle is the system health indicator. Is it blinking amber?

Comment: yes it is amber. I went through the self test of the hard drives and I got ` Error Code 0F00:1332 (some disk region number - different each time) IRQ Interrupt Request did not set in time` on disk 2. I would assume that that is the bad disk. is there anything I need to do besides change the disk and have it rebuild? heres the picture [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1SKKr1I2FkHRDhWcTgtVV9CQUFnTnp2LUxFVDZpT0JCX2dz/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you post a picture of the physical disk details and the virtual disk details?

Comment: ok here are the pictures [pictures](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1SKKr1I2FkHQUFFVmZIS3E4X1U&usp=sharing) It looks like the drives are full and thats why windows wouldn't boot.

Comment: It looks to me like you've got 2 RAID5 arrays configured across the same physical disks but only 2 physical disks in the array are Online. You've got another disk showing a Ready status and 1 disk showing a Spare status. I'm thinking you need to add the Ready disk to the RAID5 array to bring it out of it's degraded state. RAID5 requires a minimum of 3 drives.

Comment: so I removed drive 2 because it was the one that failed and put in a new disk what do I have to do to get the array to rebuild?

Comment: I believe you need to configure the new disk as a global hot spare and then the controller will rebuild it as a member of the array. Also, the "No Space Left" indicator has nothing to do with Windows booting. The "No Space Left" means that all of the available space on the physical disks has been allocated to virtual disks.

Comment: Honestly replace all 4 74gb hard drives with a 256gb or 512gb SSD. Crucial m550 or samsung 840 pro come to mind(way faster).  You might be able to boot from the windows CD to access the files.  Regardless of the OS I would boot from a Windows 7 DVD and under repair go to command prompt and see if you can access the files.

Comment: thanks for all the help I was able to get the drive to be a hot spare and get the computer back up. I did have to rebuild the SQL server but it all worked out after a bunch of work. We are going to replace the spinning drives with SSD's in raid 0 but now it is working.